What is this usage of には?

声をかけるには空気が張り詰めている。あたしは黙って、美織を見守ることにした。

"空気が張り詰めている。あたしは黙って、美織を見守ることにした。" is the atmosphere is too tense, so I stay silent and decided to watch over Miori.
What is this usage of には?

It means "for the purpose of", or "for doing x". E.g. スープとして飲むには味が濃すぎる、半袖を着るには寒すぎる. For the example in the question: "To say something to them, the atmosphere is too tense".
